# Criar o código para preencher o vetor - Javascript/Lógica

Tags: javascript, lógica

estou com um problema em um exercício sobre arrays. A questão é a seguinte:

Criar o código para preencher o array com os seguintes valores:
  **3 4 7 12 19 28 39 52 67 84**

Já fiz os outros exercícicios dessa lista, **meu problema com esse é na lógica.** Não estou conseguindo pensar em como incrementar o contador de forma que ele adicione o próximo número ímpar. Até tentei elaborar da seguinte forma:

```
if((i+1)%2==0)
{
     numero = numero+i;
     contador= i;
}
else {
     numero= numero+2;
     contador =  i;
}
```

Mas não rodou. Any help???

Comment: Acho que falta explicar melhor o que deseja e colocar o código completo. Por exemplo, qual seria o valor inicial de `i`? Onde está o array? Vc quer inserir apenas ímpares no array?

Comment: Sam, não tem código, tirei de uma lista de exercícios. Tenho que criar um código que crie o array lista= [3, 4, 7, 12, 19, 28, 39, 52, 67, 84], usando laços.  No caso entendi que o contador é incrementado em 1 no começo e vai sendo incrementado com o próximo número ímpar (1, depois 3, depois 5, ...), mas não consigo fazer isso rodar...

Comment: Certo, mas qual o valor máximo a ser adicionado?

Comment: O último incremento é no valor de 17, entre os elementos 67 e 84!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resolução:

```js
let n = 3;
let i = 1;
let a = [];

while(n <= 84){
    a.push(n);
    n += i;
    i += 2;
}

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Demais!!! Obrigada!